# Java DLL security general question

Tags: java, security, dll

I understand that Java can load/execute DLL code, but I'm wondering if there are any security checks to prevent untrusted code from the system being called by a JVM. Couldn't this destroy the system -- are there any OS features that prevent this? Or can someone just write in Java itself some method that prevents untrusted code from being loaded? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Once you call out to native code (via JNI) then that native code is free to do anything (subject to the OS itself giving permission). There's no concept of sandboxing the native code invoked from the JVM.

Note that this is a particular headache with JNI code. Badly coded native code can take down the JVM (as opposed to simply throwing an exception) and the consequent debugging/resolution is particularly hard.

Answer (score 1):

The loading of native code can itself be prevented. Typically e.g. applets run such security context that they cannot load native libraries. However, if the JVM lets your Java code call into untrusted native code, all bets are off.